# Prevent a user from renaming a file while its being streamed from a remote ftp server cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutputstream

How to avoid a user from renaming a file while its being downloaded/streamed on mac programmatically using cocoa.

Breaking my head on this since 4 hours. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, you have an application that is downloading a file from a server using FTP-- and you want to prevent the user, while the download is happening, from renaming the file... from the FTP server?

Comment: Yes MattyAyOh. Fixed it by streaming it to a temp directory and moving it. Thank you. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply download to a temporary directory (away from the user's typical view) and move/copy into its final location when complete?

Comment: Fixed it by streaming it to a temp directory and moving it. Thank you DDP. Appreciate your help.